# Add class once user scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm designing a vertical scroll website where each page is a 105% tall div.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Javascript to slap a class on a div once the user scrolls down.

The div in question is on the second page, so around 170% from the top. So far I have this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var q = 1.7;
    if(height  >= q) {
        $(window).off("scroll");
        $('#A2').addClass('animated bounceIn');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: remove the space(s) between **animated** and **bounceIn**

Comment: @Alexdn https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, I know sir. But maybe he's trying to use just one class, since he never put his HTML and never explain it very well why he put that kind of a class.

Comment: Why are you comparing `scrollTop` to the value `1.7`?

Comment: @CBroe Some random number to indicate the user scrolled down. Should not matter though. Who scrolls just 1px?

Comment: @Alexdn they are actually two separate classes. I'm using the animated.css library/plugin.

Comment: @CBroe Hold on... I meant 1.7 as in 170%. I've been trying to fix this thing for hours I completely missed it! How would I compare scrollTop to 170% instead of pixels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your script here: http://jsbin.com/dixuqoku/1/edit

To compare to 170% of the viewport height, you could just multiply the viewport height with 1.7:

```
var oneSeventy = $(window).height() * 1.7;
```